# go-pg efficient multi table/row insert

Tags: postgresql, go

What is an efficient way to write this raw PostgreSQL query using in go? I'm using `go-pg` but something with just the `pg` library should translate well to `go-pg`.

Table:

```
companies:
  - id string, primary key
  - name string, not null

services:
  - id string, primary key
  - company_id string, not null, foreign key (company.id)
  - name string, not null
```

Query:

```
WITH company AS ( INSERT INTO companies(id, name) VALUES('1', 'acme') RETURNING id)
INSERT INTO services(id, company_id, name) VALUES
('1', (select company.id from company), 'cool service'),
('2', (select company.id from company), 'cooler service');
```

This is what I came up with. It's very hacky and I feel there is a more "idiomatic" way of doing this.

```
type Company struct {
    ID string
    Name string
    Services []*Service
}

type Service struct {
    ID string
    CompanyID string
    Name string
}

c := &Company{
    ID: uuid.NewV4().String(),
    Name: "test comp",
}

s := []*Service{
    &Service{
        ID: uuid.NewV4().String(),
        Name: "test svc",
    },
}

c.Service = s

values := []interface{}{
    c.ID,
    c.Name,
}

q := `
    WITH company as (INSERT INTO companies(id, name) VALUES ($1, $2) RETURNING id) INSERT INTO services(id, company_id, name) VALUES
`

var i int = 3
for _, row := range c.Services {
    q += fmt.Sprintf("($%d, (select company.id from company), $%d),", i, i+1)
    values = append(values, row.ID, row.Name)
    i += 2
}

q = strings.TrimSuffix(q, ",")

stmt, err := DB.Prepare(q)
if err != nil {
    return err
}

if _, err := stmt.Exec(values...); err != nil {
    return err
}
```

I'm somewhat new to using go's sql library and I know I have to be missing something. I saw the pg library allows for [bulk imports](https://godoc.org/github.com/lib/pq#hdr-Bulk_imports)  but it's a bit confusing how I would do that in my case where I need to populate two separate tables the and the bulk import occurs on the second table.

Comment: Did you mean `pq` instead of `pg`?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't seem that the `pq` library has a query builder or a specific type. So building a query in an idiomatic and readable way should be done as you would do for a normal string, and that is using the [`text/template`](https://golang.org/pkg/text/template/) package. This will allow you to get rid of many code smells:

1. the line containing your query is long and not easily readable, maybe skip more lines
2. you can write the skeleton to your query once, instead of using successive appends — this is also more efficient if you have many services
3. the call to `strings.TrimSuffix` can be avoided using [a simple condition in your template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21305865/golang-separating-items-with-comma-in-template)
4. you can replace `(select company.id from company)` directly by its value, that you previously computed in your Go code
5. and you can get rid of the `[]interface{}` variable that you pass to `Prepare` & `Exec`, just do all the substitution logic in the go code.

Various unrelated things:

- Don't write `var int i = 3`, write simply `i := 3`.
- I'm not sure why `Company` and `Service` have to be exported, since you seem to only use them to build a query.
- When doing successive `+=` operations on a string, consider using a buffer instead, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760757/how-to-efficiently-concatenate-strings-in-go). (But here, it's moot, since using a template is more idiomatic.)